# Dragging objects using ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying to make all my drawn Sprites dragable for a little game. It should be able to touch anywhere and the sprites should move the same distance, the finger moves.

With the following method they will move on an ACTION_MOVE event, but only very slow, a shorter distance and sometimes they dont:
addToX/Y only adds the gap to the coordinates of the sprites

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt){
    switch(evt.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if(getHistorySize() > 0){
            for(int i = 1, n = evt.getHistorySize(); i < n; i++){
                int calcX = (int) getHistoricalX(i) - (int) getHistoricalX(i-1);
                int calcY = (int) getHistoricalY(i) - (int) getHistoricalY(i-1);
                for(Sprite sprite : spriteList) {
                    sprite.addToX(calcX);
                    sprite.addToY(calcY);
                }
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Sprite` class is an (potentially-indirect) extension of `android.view.View`, then you can use `setOnDragListener()` to define an `onDrag()` override for them.  Then you can use `startDrag(...)` on them to begin the drag.  This is typically triggered by a long-press gesture on the view to be dragged, but in your case you can trigger it from within `onTouchEvent()` in `ACTION_MOVE` *once* (or even `ACTION_DOWN`).  See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) for more details on these methods.

Also, with respect to the code you posted, one issue with it that probably explains why it doesn't always work is that you are only using the historical points (which may or may not have accumulated on any particular call to `onTouchEvent()`).  Whether or not `getHistorySize()` is greater than 0, you should still also use `evt.getX()` and `evt.getY()` on each call to `onTouchEvent()`.  But of course, if you use the drag listener approach I suggested instead, you won't need to worry about this.

---

**Update per comment**

If you want to move all of the sprites at once, you can put the sprites into a full-screen `FrameLayout` and attach a `GestureDetector` that uses a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` to capture `onScroll()` callbacks and then calls `scrollTo()` on the `FrameLayout`.  When the parent `FrameLayout` scrolls, all of its children sprites will appear to move together.

Comment: The Problem is, that I want ALL sprites to move with just 1 drag to achieve something like a scrolling effect.

Sorry if I get it wrong, but im kinda new to this.

Comment: @guennin  ah ha.  so there's an easy trick to do that.  I'll update my answer.